# Combine 2 FFMPEG commands - 1. Create a video loop and 2. Add track to loop X times / Add track to loop duration of video loop

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ffmpeg, video

I have these 2 commands for FFMPEG, but can't work out how to use the output from the first command and link into the 2nd one, and use them as a single process. I have the following:

Loop video for duration

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.m4v -c copy -t 10800 output3h.m4v
```

Add track to loop X times from .txt

```
ffmpeg -y -i output3h.m4v -f concat -i text.txt -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 -shortest complete3h.m4v
```

Can any one help link them together for 1 action? If any one knows of a way to make the audio loop for the duration of the looped video (t) instead of using the .txt that would help greatly also.

Comment: there is a similar situation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015771/merge-video-and-audio-with-ffmpeg-loop-the-video-while-audio-is-not-over/55841289#55841289 It looks like you may be able to use stream_loop for both inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream_loop for both.

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.m4v -stream_loop -1 -i audio -c:v copy -t 10800 complete3h.mp4`